# What is the gold disc on this key fob for?

Tags: automotive

As is shown in the following photo:

[image]

Comment: It's a contact for the battery.

Comment: Okay, that's what I thought, and I think it's worn out because the fob isn't working anymore. The battery is new and I replaced the fob shell less than 2 months ago and the button contacts for the new shell are still in great condition. If I put a piece of foil between the disc and the battery would that complete the circuit? Would inserting a piece of foil short out the fob? I really just don't want to have to buy a new fob.

Comment: You should try to clean (*not* scrape off!) the contact with mechanical and/or chemical means (see ["Electric Contact Cleaner Spray"](https://www.amazon.com/WD-40-Specialist-Electrical-Contact-Cleaner/dp/B00CMT9TFY) for example). Inserting some foil may or may not work temporarily, but the risk of shorting the battery this way is high.

Comment: Unless you had some sort of battery leak, it's not real likely that the gold pad isworn out.    There may be a mechanical issue with the other parts that preclude contact

Answer (score 6):

It looks like the disk, the clip above it, and the 5-edge plastic wall around part of it is a battery holder.  This is for a "coin" battery, something like a CR2032, depending on actual size.

Comment: Wow! Two down votes because I don't know too much about electronics, so much for trying to get help. I'll come back when I get a PhD in Electrical Engineering. Until then could someone direct me to electronics for dummies, help website?

Comment: @Mich: Remember that we are all volunteers here.  Nobody is obligated to help you at all.  Ranting at the one person who did actually answer your question is not how to entice people to spend their free time helping you in the future.